# Need simple php help, but I don't really know php yet

Tags: php, hyperlink

```
<div class='rate-results'>
<div class='button-container'>
    <input type='submit' id='btn-calculate' class='pure-button pure-button-primary' value='{$a['label_button_continue']}'></input>
</div><div class='rate-container'>
    <div class='label_calculated_rate'>{$a['label_calculated_rate']}</div>
    <div id='calculated_rate'>{$a['default_price']}</div>
</div>
```

how can i apply a link to this button?

```
['label_calculated_rate']
```

seems to pull the text

"GET A QUOTE"

from code up above it, but nowhere can i find how to turn this button into a link. The mentioned above code is as follows...

```
static function handle_shortcode($atts){
        self::$add_script = true;
        self::$add_styles = true;

            $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'title' => 'Get a FREE Price Estimate',
            'label_days' => 'Total days of coverage needed?',
            'units_days' => 'days',
            'label_attendance' => 'Estimated daily attendance?',
            'units_attendance' => 'people',
            'label_event_type' => 'What type of event is it?',
            'label_sample_certificate' => 'View sample certificate',
            'link_sample_certificate' => '#',
            'label_button_continue' => 'Get Free Quote',
                        'label_calculated_rate' => 'Estimated Cost',
            'default_price' => '$ 95.95',
            'form_action' => 'javascript:void(0);',
            'default_event_type' => ""
        ), $atts);

        return "<form action='{$a['form_action']}' id='main_calculator' class='pure-form pure-form-aligned' data-default-event-type='{$a['default_event_type']}'>
        <h3 class='title'>{$a['title']}</h3>
```

Comment: This looks more like you should start with basic HTML knowledge. Google how a link is created in HTML.

Comment: I know how to create a link in html, im asking how to apply a link to this button that was created in php....

Comment: The PHP is just sticking the HTML together for you; it doesn't know if you're telling it to write a button, a link, or an ASCII Art Eiffel Tower. So you add a link the same way you add the div and input and everything else.

Comment: Read http://whathaveyoutried.com/ to learn how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<div class='label_calculated_rate'>{$a['label_calculated_rate']}</div>
```

with

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/"><div class='label_calculated_rate'>{$a['label_calculated_rate']}</div></a>
```

Replace `http://www.w3schools.com/html/` with where you want the button to link to.

Hence adding a link to the button:

```
['label_calculated_rate']
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. That's more the type of answer I was looking for. It did however, return the following error...


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'https' (T_STRING) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas04_data03/37/2340737/html/wp-content/plugins/rate-calculator/rate-calculator.php on line 74


Here is the code with your suggested changes...

Comment: <div class='rate-results'>
 <div class='button-container'>
  <input type='submit' id='btn-calculate' class='pure-button pure-button-primary' value='{$a['label_button_continue']}'></input>
 </div><div class='rate-container'>
  <a href="https://secure.directeventinsurance.com"><div class='label_calculated_rate'>{$a['label_calculated_rate']}</div></a>
  <div id='calculated_rate'>{$a['default_price']}</div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: ive tinkered around trying to add the html code in other areas, have had no luck yet...

Comment: That sounds like a different error. Does the error go away when you undo the change? Whats around line 74 in rate-calculator.php? Sounds like its missing something.